# drupal 7: save checkboxes status in block configuration

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have created this block, that contains 6 checkboxes:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function menu_square_block_info() {
    $blocks['menu_square'] = array(
        'info' => t('Block Square'),
        //'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    );

    return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function menu_square_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'menu_square':
            $block['subject'] = t('block Title');
            $block['content'] = t(
                '<div id="menu-square" class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 box">
                            <a href="/search/?f[0]=type%3Abrigadista">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>Brigadistas</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 box">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>Fuentes Documentales</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 box">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>Encuadramientos militares</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-lg-4 box">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>Proyecto Sidbrint</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 box">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>Colaboradores</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 box">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>Noticias</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>'
            );
            break;
    }
    return $block;
}

/*
 * Implements hock_block_configure().
 **/
function menu_square_block_configure($delta='') {
    $form = array();

    switch($delta) {
    case 'menu_square':
        $boxes = array(
            'brigadistes' => t('brigadistes'),
            'fonts_documentals' => t('fonts_documentals'),
            'encuadraments_militars' => t('encuadraments_militars'),
            'projecte_sidbrint' => t('projecte_sidbrint'),
            'colaboradors' => t('colaboradors'),
            'noticies' => t('noticies')
        );    

        // Text field form element
        $form['boxes'] = array(
            '#title' => t('Capses a mostrar'),
            '#type' => 'checkboxes',
            '#description' => t('selecciona les capses a mostrar.'),
            '#options' => $boxes,
            '#default_value' => variable_get('boxes', array()),
        );
        break;
    }
    return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_save().
 */
function menu_square_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {
    switch($delta) {
    case 'menu_square' :
        // Saving the WYSIWYG text      
        variable_set('checkboxes_boxes', $edit['boxes']);
  }
}
```

I'm having a problem because when I select some checkboxes in the block configuration and save it, the checkboxes are unchecked. So I don't know how to save values.

How I can save the checkboxes that are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow this code..

// Text field form element

```
        $default = variable_get('checkboxes_boxes', array());
        $form['boxes'] = array(
            '#title' => t('Capses a mostrar'),
            '#type' => 'checkboxes',
            '#description' => t('selecciona les capses a mostrar.'),
            '#options' => $boxes,
            '#default_value' => $default,
        );
        break;
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Here, change the  **variable_get('checkboxes_boxes', array())** and it pass after to store into $default variable.

Comment: I don't want to check all checkboxes, only I want to check the checkboxes that were checked and saved previously

Comment: A reminder that "hope this helps" material is still present in 398 of your answers, and it is too chatty and redundant for Stack Overflow. I've been trying to remove it, and you have at least refrained from this for a while after a diamond moderator also removed it from some of your questions. Please write future answers without this phrase.